# Linker copytable meaning

Tags: c, linker, embedded

I'm trying to compile an embedded C project using tasking compiler on TRICORE TC275 board. when using linker option `LINK_OPT += --user-provided-initialization-code` I got the following error :

```
ltc E122: copy table construction error for "task1": The linker detected references to the copytable, while options indicate that custom initialization code is used.
```

1. what does copytable mean ?
2. how can I fix this ?

**linker snippet:**

```
/* Linker script for the TRICORE system. */

architecture TC
{
    endianness
    {
        little;
    }

    space linear
    {
        id = 1;
        mau = 8;

        map (src_offset=0x00000000, dest_offset=0x00000000, size=4G, dest=bus:fpi_bus);

        copytable (align = 1 << 2, copy_unit = 1, dest = linear);
    }

    bus fpi_bus
    {
        mau = 8;
        width = 32;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tasking compiler copytable is used to copy sections(.data etc) from  ROM  to  RAM at startup.
Your program may be using custom initialization code to  achieve this.
Removing the "copytable" refernce from the linker script should produce no error.

Alternatively you can remove the linker option

```
LINK_OPT += --user-provided-initialization-code
```

If you are not intending to use custom initialization code and use the linker provided copytable to copy constants from ROM to RAM at startup.